# Relative layout is overlapping toolbar in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

I have got the following layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="This will run the marquee animation forever"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/share"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/segment_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_one"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="    A      "
                    android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_text_selector"
                />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_two"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector_right"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="    B      "
                    android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_text_selector"/>

            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"/>

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/play_song_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/dark_navy_blue"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/light_navy_blue"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Im trying to put up the relative layout below the toolbar. I tried adding         `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` but still it does not works. I tried adding `android:paddingTop` and `android:marginTop` attributes. Adding these attributes works fine in interface but when it comes to real device, the relative layout is still overlapping the toolbar. why so?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `Toolbar` layout inside `AppBarLayout`. Like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        // Your Toolar herer
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried it though. Replacing my code in this code doesnt work

Comment: Remove codes: `app:layout_anchor="@+id/share"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"`